# Why using <!-- and //--> in HTML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner of HTML, and I'm learning javascript now.

I read something strange in my book.

I know that `<!-- ~~~~ -->` is a remark.

But in my book, and in my code, that code did nothing, even not remark.

I want to know why `<!-- ~~~~ //-->`, not `<!-- ~~~~ -->`.

And I also want to know why do we use it, and why that code don't do anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not *code*, it's a *comment*.

Comment: your book must be **old** ... `<!-- ~~~~ //-->` is what you'd do in an inline script so browsers that didn't know about javascript wouldn't render the script as text - it's pretty much not needed unless you want to use NCSA Mosaic or something

Comment: @naeramarth7 what are differences between code and comment?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah my book is very old. Then do people usually don't use that code?

Comment: @Andreas Oh you're right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the early days of browsers, there were some that didn't even have a javascript engine

they treated `<script>` as just an unknown tag, but rendered the content anyway

So, to avoid this, one would write inline javascript like

```
<script><!--
    javascript goodness in here
//--></script>
```

the `//-->` was so browsers that DID have javascript didn't choke on

```
-->
```

which is invalid syntax

```
// anything here
```

is a single line comment in javascript

There is absolutely no reason to put such things in code now, however, most (if not all) engines will still not "break" when (the first line of?) inline script contains

```
<!--
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can understand it. So I don't really need to use that code, right?

Comment: Exactly, I doubt there are any browsers in existence that don't include a JS engine

Comment: Alright. Now I know what that code means and the fact my book is very old... :)

Comment: And at this time, XHTML was a still thing, so you'd even want `//<![CDATA[` so that you could write `i<3` without breaking the parsing.